# "Waiting for AppCache" in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have noticed that fairly frequently my browser "*freezes*" with `Waiting for AppCache` message at the bottom.

I'm using `Win 7 64-bit`.  `Version 39.0.2171.95 m` of Chrome (which seems to be up-to-date).  My laptop uses wired connection to Belkin router.

I also noticed (could be something unrelated) that **https** (SSL) connections are rather slow on the first try.

I've done simple browser cache clean-up.

This is more an annoyance than a real problem for me (at least for now).